# VueJS Select only one element in a v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue v2

I'm trying to change only the properties of the selected element. See, when the response is marked after the click, it should change to a red color with a text that says 'Unmark'. And vice versa: if the button is clicked again (which now would say 'Unmark'), it should change to a green color and the text would be 'Mark'. Alas, it works.... Nevertheless, my code applies the change to every element inside the v-for; I only want that to happen to the selected element.

I've thought about using a Component to check if somethings changes, but first I'd like to see if there's a solutions for this. ANy help will be appreciated

Here's my code:

```
<div class="search-results">
                <div class="activity-box-w" v-for="user in users">
                    <div class="box">
                      <div class="avatar" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + user.customer.profile_picture + ')' }">
                      </div>
                      <div class="info">
                        <div class="role">
                          @{{ '@' + user.username }}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <p class="title">@{{ user.customer.name }} 
                                @{{user.customer.lastname}}
                                </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="time">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" v-on:click.prevent="markUser(user)" v-model="text" 
                        v-bind:class="[{'green-border':notMarked}, {'red-border':marked}]" v-cloak v-if="!action"
                        :disabled="action"></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now for the script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#engage-panel',
  data: {
    users: [],
    mark: {'id' : '', 'marks' : ''},
    text: 'Mark', //Migth change to Unmark later on
    action: false,
    marked: null,
    notMarked: null,
  }, 
    methods:
{   
markUser: function(user){

      this.mark.id = user.id;
      this.action= true;

      Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      this.$http.put('/mark/user', this.mark).then(response => {

                  if(response.body === "marked")
                  {
                      this.mark.marks="true";
                      this.text = 'Unmark';
                      this.marked= true;
                      this.notMarked= false;
                      this.action= false;

                  }else{
                      this.mark.marks="false";                  
                      this.text = 'Mark';
                      this.marked= false;
                      this.notMarked= true;
                      this.action= false;
                  }

                }).catch(e => {

                    this.action= false;
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you store the selected state anywhere?

Comment: I don't think so, how can I do that and what would it do to help?

Comment: Put something like selectedUser to data, then do v-if="selectedUser === user" inside the for loop.

Comment: I added the selectedUser to data:{...} and set it to null by default. Where am I supposed to put the v-if? In the input tag which I'm using? I put this inside the function to see if something changes: "this.selectedUser = user;" and it's still the same. Maybe I'm doing wrong something of what you told me

Comment: what happen with `v-on:click.prevent(this)` and you start from here to change the properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$event.target` on click if you just need to toggle css class.
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/Les32jjn/)

But it's true that it's easier if a user has a status like `marked = true/false` for example, you just need to bind class like :

```
<input :class="{ 'green-border': user.marked, 'red-border': !user.marked }">
```

Comment: Yes! This is just what I needed. I was completely overlooking that fact (I do indeed have a property called "user_is_marked") And now it works completely. Thanks for your answer, and as well to Sphinx

Comment: @NoviceMav direct touch dom is not recommended. For Vue, we prefer a “data-driven” fashion

Answer (score 1):

The issue `my code applies the change to every element` you met is caused by every user in `v-for="user in users"` uses one same object to indicates it is marked or not.

If your `users` data has one property like status to save current status (like unmark, mark etc), it is very simple, just change to next status when click **mark** button.

If your `users` data doesn't have that property, you need to create one dictionary, then save the users already clicked as key, the status for the user will be the value.

Below is one demo:

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users1: [{'name':'abc', 'status':'none'},
            {'name':'xyz', 'status':'none'}],
    users2: [{'name':'abc'}, {'name':'xyz'}],
    selectedUsers: {}
  },
  methods: {
    getNextStatusBaseOnRoute: function (status) {
      if(status ==='marked') return 'marked'
      let routes = {'none':'unmark', 'unmark':'marked'}
      return routes[status]
    },
    markUser1: function (item) {
      item.status = this.getNextStatusBaseOnRoute(item.status)
    },
    markUser2: function (item) {
      let status = item.name in this.selectedUsers ? this.selectedUsers[item.name] : 'none'
      // remember to use vue.$set when adding new property to one object
      this.$set(this.selectedUsers, item.name, this.getNextStatusBaseOnRoute(status))
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.marked {
  background-color:green;
}

.unmark {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <h2>Case 1: </h2>
    <div v-for="(item, index1) in users1" :key="'1'+index1">
      <span>{{item.name}}:</span><span :class="[item.status]">{{item.status}}</span><button @click="markUser1(item)">Mark</button>
    </div>
    <h2>Case 2: </h2>
    <div v-for="(item, index2) in users2" :key="'2'+index2">
      <span>{{item.name}}:</span><span :class="[item.name in selectedUsers ? selectedUsers[item.name] : 'none']">{{item.name in selectedUsers ? selectedUsers[item.name] : 'none'}}</span><button @click="markUser2(item)">Mark</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Vue3, you can also store the index of the selected element

```
<ul role="list" class="">
  <li class="relative" v-for="(image, index) of images" :class="selectedImage == index? 'border-indigo-500 border-2': 'border-transparent'" >
    <div @click="selectedImage = index" class="">
      <img :src="image" alt="" class="object-cover pointer-events-none group-hover:opacity-75">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```